# Return a pointer to the last appearance of a character in a C-Style string (C++)

Tags: c++, string

Return a pointer to the last appearance of c
appearing inside s and nullptr (0) if c does not appear inside s.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

const char* myStrRChr(const char* s, char c)
{
    int curIdx = 0;
    char last;

    while (s[curIdx] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[curIdx] == c)
            last = s[curIdx];
        curIdx++;
    }
    if (s[curIdx] == c)
        return last;
    else
        // return '\0', nullptr, NULL
        return "";
}


int main()
{
    char cstr[50] = "Abadabadoo!";
    char buf[10];
    const char * cat = "cat";
    char dog[] = "Labradoodle";

    cout << "\nmyStrRChr(cstr, 'a') expects adoo!" << endl;
    cout << "  -- " << myStrRChr(cstr, 'a') << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code returns "adabadoo!". I can't wrap my mind around as to how to get the last instance of "char c."

Comment: you need a pointer not an index?

Comment: You need to find out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: That `while` loop is infinite.  Are you sure this is the code you're using?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, forgot to add it in. Edited.

Comment: You return the *first* match you find.  Instead, you should remember its location and keep going.  When you get to the end, *then* return the saved value.

Comment: What would I use to store the location? It is a const char*
        int curIdx = 0;
    size_t last;
    
    while (s[curIdx] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[curIdx] == c)
            last = curIdx;
        s++;
    }
    return last;

Comment: That code would not even compile as C++, due to the `return last`  (`last` is of type `char`, the function returns a pointer), let alone give unexpected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by obtaining a pointer to the end of the string and decrementing down the string searching for the character `c`, and a pointer to the beginning of the string to know where to stop looping:

```
const char *mystrrchr(const char *str, char c)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *p = const_cast<char *>(&str[len-1]);
    char *stop = const_cast<char *>(&str[0]);
    while(p>=stop)
    {
        if(*p==c)
        {
            return p;
        }
        p--;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this particular problem takes the parameters of a const char* str and char c. It is supposed to return a const char* as well. How would you go about this to accommodate the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! I appreciate the explanation.